# How to store data from a file into a dictionary?

Tags: python

How can I store data from a file into a dictionary?

```
Living Room,23
Bedroom,24
Kitchen,22
Living Room,24
Bedroom,26
Kitchen,22
Living Room,25
Bedroom,26
Kitchen,23
Living Room,24
Bedroom,26
Kitchen,23
```

The values of each room supposed to be summed up.

And, dictionary supposed to look like this:

```
data = {'Living room':[23,24,25,24],'Bedroom':[24,26,26,26],'Kitchen':[22,22,23,23]}
```

My code:

```
with open('temps1.txt', 'r') as file:
  inp = [i.strip().replace(',',' ').split() for i in file]
  keys = list(set(' '.join(i[:-1]) for i in inp))
  values = [float(i[-1]) for i in inp]
  data = dict(zip(keys, [values]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dict.setdefault`.

**Ex:**

```
data = {}
with open('temps1.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        key, value = line.strip().split(",")
        data.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

---

You can also use `csv` module since you have comma separated data

**Ex:**

```
import csv

data = {}
with open('temps1.txt', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for key, value in reader:
        data.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

Comment: Man, I was just writing the answer...^_^

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

with open('temps1.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        k, v = line.split(',')    
        data[k].append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple example (If you don't want to use the `defaultdict`, `setdefault` or other "fancies"). I have used the same input file as yours.

**Code:**

```
data = {}
with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        room, number = line.strip().split(",")
        if room in data:
            data[room].append(number)
            continue
        data[room] = [number]

print("\nResult:{}\n".format(data))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py

Result:{'Living Room': ['23', '24', '25', '24'], 'Bedroom': ['24', '26', '26', '26'], 'Kitchen': ['22', '22', '23', '23']}
```